# Implicit default constructor not generated VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker-errors, auto, default-constructor

I'm getting a linker error in VS2010 SP1 compiling and linking the code below, saying that it cannot find the symbol Base::Base(void).

Seems like the implicit default constructor does not get generated.

If I choose to initialize b as follows `const Base& b = *d;`, it just works fine. If I make d a `Derived*` it works. Finally if I make `dosomething` not pure virtual but virtual, it also works.

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong ? I tried compiling the code online here http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php and it works fine.

```
struct Base
{
    virtual void dosomething() const  = 0;
};

struct Derived : Base
{
    virtual void dosomething() const override { }
};

int main()
{
    Base* d = new Derived();
    const auto& b = *d;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug. No-repro with VS2012, so I'd consider it fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is fine WRT `Base`, nothing to prevent the ctor being generated. Looks like a bug in VS2010

Comment: Ok thanks, as mentionned by Xeo it seems like it has been fixed in VS2012 (I only have VS2010 and [VS2012 online compiler](http://rise4fun.com/Vcpp) does not link so I could not test it. I also tried to check if this was listed under [VS2012 compiler bug fixes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/08/10/10338661.aspx) but as mentionned in the post, the list is far from being exhaustive.